# Change the size on only part of a map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

Here is a reproducible example. I have obtained the US and UK maps. My question is how to double the size of UK part without changing the size of US part on the same plot. Thanks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(ggthemes)
map_uk<- st_as_sf(ne_countries(country = 'united kingdom' , 
                                            type = 'map_units')) %>% 
  select(country = admin, name, geometry)

map_us <- st_as_sf(ne_states(country = "united states of america"
                                         )) %>% 
  select(country = admin, name, geometry) %>% 
  filter(!name %in% c("Alaska", "Hawaii"))
map_both <- map_uk %>% rbind(map_us)
map_both %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = name)) + 
  theme_map() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with `cowplot` :

Here is my attempt :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(ggthemes)
library(cowplot)

map_uk<- st_as_sf(ne_countries(country = 'united kingdom' , 
                               type = 'map_units')) %>% 
  select(country = admin, name, geometry)

map_us <- st_as_sf(ne_states(country = "united states of america")) %>% 
  select(country = admin, name, geometry) %>%
  filter(!name %in% c("Alaska", "Hawaii"))


US <- ggplot(data=map_us) + 
  geom_sf() +
  theme_map()

UK <- ggplot(data=map_uk) + 
  geom_sf() +
  theme_map()



ggdraw() + draw_plot(US, x=0,y=0,width = 0.75, height = 0.8) + draw_plot(UK, x=0.65,y=0.4,width = 0.45, height = 0.4)
```

[image]

Second attempt

```
map_both <- map_uk %>% rbind(map_us)

both <- map_both %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = name)) + 
  theme_map() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")


UK2 <- both %+% subset(map_both,country %in% c("United Kingdom"))
US2 <- both %+% subset(map_both,country %in% c("United States of America"))

plot_grid(US2,UK2,ncol=2, scale=c(1,0.4))
```

[image]